# using setState with an array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having a state with two products like this:

```
const [product, setProduct] = useState([
    {
      name: 'Hat',
      description: 'Nice cartoon hat',
      images: [
        'linktoimage',
      ],
      amount: 799,
      currency: 'eur',
      quantity: 0,
    },
    {
      name: 'Gift',
      description: 'Nice cartoon gift',
      images: [
        'linktoimage',
      ],
      amount: 599,
      currency: 'eur',
      quantity: 0,
    },
  ]);
```

I want to display them so I use a regular mapping  :

```
<div className='product'>
        {product.map((p) => (
          <div>
            <h3>{p.name}</h3>
            <h4>
              Stripe Amount:{' '}
              {(p.amount / 100).toLocaleString('en-US', {
                style: 'currency',
                currency: 'EUR',
              })}
            </h4>
            <img src={p.images[0]} width='250px' alt='product' />
           
            <span style={{ margin: '20px', fontSize: '2em' }}>
              {p.quantity}
            </span>

            <button
              className='btn btn-sm btn-success'
              onClick={() => {
          
                setProduct([...p, (p.quantity = Math.max(0, p.quantity + 1))]);
              }}
            >
              +
            </button>
          </div>
        ))}
```

I am having hard time changing the quantity  ( my last button) all I want is to change the products quantity but i cant do it somehow

tried like this:

```
  onClick={() => {setProduct([...p, (p.quantity = Math.max(0, p.quantity + 1))]);
}}
```

says that **p** is not iterable, i did another thing but when I inceremented my other product disappeared , i guess it is because I set the productState to ...p .

How can I incerement the given  **p** product without losing my other product in my state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a way you can do to update the quantity of element:

> ```
> ...
> {product.map((p, indx) => (
> ...
>           <button
>               className='btn btn-sm btn-success'
>               onClick={() => {
>                   const updateProducts = product
>                   updateProducts[indx].quantity += 1
>                   setProduct([...updateProducts])
>               }}
>             >
>               +
>          </button>
> }}
> ))
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to increment `quantity` outside the `setProduct` and then set state:

```
onClick={() => {
  let result = [...product];
  result = result.map((x) => {
     x.quantity = Math.max(0, x.quantity + 1);
     return x;
  });
  setProduct(result);
}}
```

Comment: thanks, but how do I increment the only the product that needs to be incremented?  Because right now both of my items is being incremented

Comment: @Mynameisjeff its just necessary to add a condition inside the `map`. Something like: `result = result.map((x) => {
     if (condition) x.quantity = Math.max(0, x.quantity + 1);
     return x;
  });`

Answer (score 0):

`p` is referring to an individual product while your state `product` is referring to the list of all products, so in order to update one item while preserving the rest of the list the same, you need to spread `product` first and then spread your specific item.

```
onClick={() => setProduct([...product, {...p, quantity: p.quantity + 1}])}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([
    {
      name: "Hat",
      description: "Nice cartoon hat",
      images: ["linktoimage"],
      amount: 799,
      currency: "eur",
      quantity: 0,
    },
    {
      name: "Gift",
      description: "Nice cartoon gift",
      images: ["linktoimage"],
      amount: 599,
      currency: "eur",
      quantity: 0,
    },
  ]);

  const handleIncrQuantity = (product) => () => {
    const updatedProducts = products.map((p) => {
      if (p.name === product.name) {
        return {
          ...product,
          quantity: Math.max(0, product.quantity + 1),
        };
      } else {
        return p;
      }
    });

    setProducts(updatedProducts);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {products.map((product) => (
        <div>
          {/* show your product details */}
          {JSON.stringify(product,null,4)}
          {product.quantity}
          <button
            className="btn btn-sm btn-success"
            onClick={handleIncrQuantity(product)}
          >
            +
          </button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```